# Geocode distance on a defined route

Tags: php, geocode

I am working on a mobile web site for a MS Bike event.  I already have geo code for tagging email requests, and a check-in site to check riders in to a location based on their location.  I would like to add the distance to the next rest stop / finish.  I know how to figure out the distance between two locations. And all my research on this, it to allow Google to provide the route.  But since this is an event, there is a predetermined route that the riders ride.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to tackle this?  I have the Lat/Long of the routes (each corner and turn) and I have it in a kml format.

Comment: I'd be interested in any responses to this as well. I know MongoDB offers a find.near (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/near/) providing you're actually using mongodb. Perhaps you just need to take the current location, find the nearest point to the planned route, then then add the rest of the defined route from that point?

Comment: Do you also have the lat / long of each rest stop? In which case, you just need to display the distance between each? I'm interested in this, also, and just wanted to make sure I was understanding correctly.

Comment: I have the points for the rest stops and the route is made up of points.  Basically want to find the remaining distance for the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the resolution of the way-points is distinct enough I can see two cases: The nearest way-point is either the next point or was the previous point:

[image]

So if you not only calculate the distance to the nearest point but also to the previous and next to it, you should be able to simply decide which one the next is.

As written, this requires that the resolution between the points is good enough. E.g. if you have a course with a 180 degree curve things don't evaluate that well any longer:

[image]

The solution is to have enough way-points in these areas then. So this might or might not be suitable for your problem. Sorry for the trashy graphics, but I hope they illustrate this well enough. Also the concept is a bit rough, but probably good enough to create a first mock.

Comment: That is the solution I thought of too.  Yes lots of points.  The main ride does not loop so not as much of an issue. I have one ride that is two loops so I'll have to play with it.  Now to work out the methods to do this cleanly.  I think the graphics are great.  Something I would do.  I'll have to post what I figure out. Thanks -Phil